# C++ double pointer cast

Tags: c++

This code is invalid and does not compile:

```
struct A { int x; };

struct B : public A {};

void f( B** p ){
    A** pa = p; // type mismatch
}
```

It looks innocent though, and it appears to work with `reinterpret_cast`.  I understand that there are cases where this wouldn't be so simple, e.g. when multiple inheritance is involved, but in this particular case here there shouldn't be any problem, and the compiler should be able to figure this out.  So why is this not allowed in C++?  And is `reinterpret_cast` a good way around this limitation, considering exactly the types given above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even in this simple case there is a problem, since you could change a pointer to `B` to point to an instance of `A` if this conversion were allowed:

```
A aObj;
B *bPtr;

A **aPtrPtr = &bPtr;
*aPtrPtr = &aObj;
```

The last line sets the `bPtr` to point to `aObj`. So now a pointer to `B` actually points to an instance of `A`.

Answer (score 5):

What might happen were it allowed:

```
struct A { int x; };

struct B : public A { int y; };

//...

B b;
B* pb = &b;
A** ppa = &pb;
A a;
*ppa = &a; // ppa points to pb, thus henceforth, pb == &a
pb->y = 100; // oops!
```